# Unity 5 NetUI - How do I fix this error?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

This error message keeps showing everytime I test the game:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SetupLocalPlayer.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/SetupLocalPlayer.cs:12)

and I'm trying to figure out how to enable my Wheeldrive script when I am the local player (When I spawn in) and it doesn't seem to be working, The Network Id is on the player prefab but the controller script is on the Sedan gameobject, since the Network identity is on the player prefab the disable script also has to go on it, so I don't think the script is able to find the controller script since its not on the same Gameobject. (Picture Below)

Any help is really appreciated :)
[The Project + Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znEeX.png)

Comment: SetupLocalPlayer.cs code would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `SetupLocalPlayer` script is on the player prefab, You should be able to find the `WheelDrive` component using `GetComponentInChildren<WheelDrive>()` instead of `GetComponent<WheelDrive>()` (in line 12 of the `SetupLocalPlayer.cs` file)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `WheelDrive` component is not enabled, `GetComponent` is unable to find it. Thus `GetComponent<WheelDrive>()` returns null, and you get the error in the console.